# import python modules directly from raw git tree

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have the following directory directly in a git tree that I'd like to reference by adding its base directory to PYTHONPATH without needing to package and install the modules.

Once added to PYTHONPATH, if the inner cstruct dir was pulled out one level then since it has a **init**.py file, it's trivial to just do an

```
import cstruct
```

however, since I'm also keeping the setup files, it needs to be nested another level which makes importing like above not work.

Is there any way to get around this?  I was thinking about constructing some **init**.py in the base dir that could "pull" the inner cstruct out or somehow add the outermost cstruct to the python path but I'm not sure how to go about it.

For clarity, I'm using cstruct here as an example that I pulled from github however I have a half-dozen such libs that I'd really like to just reference ad-hoc in my dev environment without needing to package + install.

```
.
├── cstruct
│   ├── cstruct
│   │   ├── examples
│   │   │   ├── fdisk.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── tests
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── test_cstruct.py
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── MANIFEST.in
│   ├── mbr
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── setup.cfg
│   └── setup.py
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of installing it in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you don't install this in a virtualenv, but given your specific question, why can you not simply do what you initially propose and add the outer directory to the PYTHONPATH?

You can either do that from the shell:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/outer/cstruct
```

or from inside Python:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/outer/cstruct')
```

Comment: I think the idea was to almost treat the base directory . like site-packages where one can just add it to their python path and all modules under the tree would be available.  Can that sys.path.insert not be done in a __init__.py in the basedir?

Comment: Yes but then you need to import that base dir, in order to get that `__init__.py` to be executed. Not sure how that helps.

Comment: That's what I was initially outlining - to simply add the basedir alone, but when I try it doesn't seem to work.